# Is @transaction.atomic cheap?

Tags: django, database, django-models

This is mostly curiosity, but is the DB penalty for wrapping an entire view with `@transaction.atomic` a negligible one?

I'm thinking of views where the GET of a form or its re-display after a validation fail involves processing querysets. (ModelChoiceFields, for example, or fetching an object that the template displays.)

It seems to me to be far more natural to use `with transaction.atomic()` around the block of code which actually alters a bunch of related DB objects only after the user's inputs have validated.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, It's best to keep transactions as small as possible (There is a performance cost for the database server). This is mentioned in a note in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) titled "Performance considerations" (You will need to scroll to the bottom of the linked section to find that note)

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't spotted this. It says "Open transactions have a performance cost for your database server. To minimize this overhead, keep your transactions as short as possible. This is especially important if you’re using atomic() in long-running processes, outside of Django’s request / response cycle.". Can't find any indication of effect of short duration transactions during views that don't actually write to the DB, which is what I was wondering about.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code:

```
def atomic(using=None, savepoint=True, durable=False):
    # Bare decorator: @atomic -- although the first argument is called
    # `using`, it's actually the function being decorated.
    if callable(using):
        return Atomic(DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS, savepoint, durable)(using)
    # Decorator: @atomic(...) or context manager: with atomic(...): ...
    else:
        return Atomic(using, savepoint, durable)
```

It's the same. In both cases the function is returning an `Atomic` object which handles whether the transaction should commit or not.

Comment: I meant, doesn't creating a transaction cause some slowdown on the DB itself between creation and commit? Rollback-ability can't come free, but is it cheap?

Comment: This guy explains it pretty well. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=omizQEkTcl4